# Can I share some content to Google+ from my iOS app without any dialog views?

Tags: ios, google-plus, social-networking

I try to implement background (without dialogs) activity sharing in my iOS app. I have done it for Facebook and Twitter using SLRequest, but can't do this feature for Google+.
Is it possible for G+?

Comment: We can, but for authorisation it will switch to browser and then back to ur app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share to Google+ in iOS you will have to use the [Google provided UI](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/). The exception is if all of your users are [Google Apps for Business](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) customers.

Comment: Thank you! But I have already read the documentation. I asked a concrete question, and I need a simple answer.

Comment: As I said: "you will have to use the Google provided UI"